# Disable interaction between list and checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have created a ul list with checkbox added, but when i select a checkbox a list item also gets selected, how can i select only a checkbox .I am adding list items theough jquery.

```js
$('#projects-menu').append("<li  value='sales1'><input class='myCheckBoxes' type='checkbox' checked>Sales 1</li>")
$('#projects-menu').append("<li  value='sales2'><input class='myCheckBoxes' type='checkbox'>Sales 2</li>")
```

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
vertical-align: middle;
float: right;
cursor: pointer;
}
ul.menu{
margin-top: 30px;
list-style-type: none;  
}
ul.menu li{
background-color:#e0e0e0;
padding: 8px 12px;
border: solid 2px white;
cursor: pointer;
border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 10px;
}
ul.menu li:hover{
background-color:#A9A9A9;
}
ul.menu li.selected{
background-color: #23ac61;
}
ul.menu li.disabled{
pointer-events: none;
opacity:0.6;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
vertical-align: middle;
float: right;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="projects">
<ul class="menu" id="projects-menu">         
</ul>
</div>
```

image shown is the  result i am getting both the checkbox and list item is selected when i select checkbox[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: Can you add the data `projectName ` what is that how does it looks like ?

Comment: The `projectName` / `String.raw ${value[projectName]}` doesn't seem relevant to the question and is hiding the actual issue/question - please update to remove this if it's not relevant.

Comment: *when i select a checkbox a list item also gets selected* - what does this mean?  How are you "selecting a checkbox" and how are you checking that the "li also gets selected"?

Comment: Thats just a background color getting applied. when you select the checkbox - i do not think its an issue here - Please add your CSS

Comment: what does an interaction means here in the image - you mean green color is getting applied - when you check a checkbox ?

Comment: Yes the color is applied

Comment: I've taken the liberty of removing the server-side code in your HTML - please update the snippet so that it **demonstrates the issue** - at the moment, what your describing is not happening in the snippet.   Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check that current checkbox is checked or not using jQuery **.is(':checked')** function. Based on it you can add **disabled** class to the parent li tag.

Please refer below solution.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>List Checkbox</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <style>
        input[type=checkbox] {
            vertical-align: middle;
            float: right;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        ul.menu {
            margin-top: 30px;
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        ul.menu li {
            background-color: #e0e0e0;
            padding: 8px 12px;
            border: solid 2px white;
            cursor: pointer;
            border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        ul.menu li:hover {
            background-color: #A9A9A9;
        }

        ul.menu li.selected {
            background-color: #23ac61;
        }

        ul.menu li.disabled {
            /* pointer-events: none; */
            /* opacity: 0.6; */
        }

        ul.menu li.disabled:hover {
            background-color: #e0e0e0;
            cursor:default;
        }

        input[type=checkbox] {
            vertical-align: middle;
            float: right;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#projects-menu').append("<li  value='sales1' class='disabled'><input class='myCheckBoxes' type='checkbox' checked>Sales 1</li>")
            $('#projects-menu').append("<li  value='sales2'><input class='myCheckBoxes' type='checkbox'>Sales 2</li>")
            $('#projects-menu li').click(function(event) {
             
                if (!$(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
                    $('#projects-menu li').removeClass('selected');
                    $(this).addClass('selected');
                } 
            })
            $(".myCheckBoxes").click(function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
               
            })
        
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="projects">
        <ul class="menu" id="projects-menu">
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: When i select a checkbox the list item should not be selected and here list item is not being selected separately

Comment: Both list selection and checlbox selection have to be done separately

Comment: Here once you disabled the list item you can't uncheck the checkbox again? Is this expected behaviour

Comment: NO..If we disable list we cannot choose the list item and checkbox must be able to uncheck and check..similarly list item also

Comment: So I think the answer I have updated just now solves your query right?

Comment: The answer you have updated i am not able to uncheck and select the list items separtely

Comment: I have added li.disabled:hover class. Don't use pointer-events: none here as it blocks all the events in the checkbox also. Please check updated answer.

Comment: I want a functionality similar to what they have provided in this link https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/web_EN/exemples/check-listbox/index.html

Comment: In the result we can select list item  and checkboxes separately

Comment: @kavya Please check updated code. I have handled it separately.

Comment: But on selection of checkbox list is also being selected

Comment: Added event.stopPropagation to prevent parent click. Also I have updated change event to click for checkboxes

Comment: Thank you for the reply..But this will not work if some list items are disabled..as we have removed disabled CSS

Comment: @kavya handled disable scenario also